# How Node.js is different from Tomcat

Tags: node.js, rest, tomcat

I am new to Node and still going through it. I have some doubts:

1. Being a server-side framework, how is it different than Tomcat?
2. If I am producing some REST APIs, can I host them on a Node server or do I need another server?

Answer (score 60, accepted):

To answer your first question, Tomcat and Node are **completely** different beasts, although you can get Node to serve the same purpose as Tomcat if you're agnostic to the programming language you're going to use and you add the right stuff on top of it.

- Tomcat is a **web server** for **web applications** written in
  **java**.
- Node is a **runtime environment** for **applications** in
  **javascript**.

So apart from the difference in the programming language, the comparison you're making is not really even. You see, Node (plus the underlying V8 engine) is more of the equivalent of the JVM (Java Virtual Machine) than Tomcat.

You can develop any type of application on Node. A subset of those will be server applications, and then a subset of that will be web server applications.

Now, perhaps the most commonly used web server on Node is [Express](http://expressjs.com/).
I honestly don't know of another. I found Express and never looked for anything else.

So, for the purpose of comparison, think of it like this:

```
JVM vs. V8+Node
Java vs. Javascript
Tomcat vs. Express
```

As for your second question, yes you can build REST API's on Node, provided you add Express on top of it. And the good news is that it is extremely simple.
Have a look at this:
http://expressjs.com/en/guide/routing.html

Good luck and have fun learning Node. I had tons. Left Java and never looked back ;)

Comment: Thanks Mig82.. This is the best explanation I got till now and it solved my doubts. Thanks for that

Comment: No problem @ChandanGupta. Do you think you could mark mine as the answer then? Thank you.

Comment: I have a follow up question that's been eating at me since I learned node. It says not go use it for CPU intensive applications but isn't ANY process doing anything considered CPU intensive?

Comment: Node was conceived for the web, to handle large amounts of concurrent requests. It's event driven and focused on asynchronous/non-blocking operations, because that's what most web applications do. It was not designed for "CPU intensive" code. Meaning, if your code does a lot of in-memory calculations you risk keeping the main thread busy enough to stop responding to the events in the event loop. Picture complex heavy algorithms like the ones used 3D modeling or image analysis. Node is not as good a match for these tasks as say C++. I recommend you read a bit of Node's history.

Comment: Not sure that I completely agree with the accepted answer.  
JVM ~ V8, 
JRE ~ Node, 
Spring Boot/micro framework/etc. ~ Express, maybe throw Tomcat in here as well since Tomcat supports a subset of JEE

Comment: If I am not the wrong, Tomcat does not go with Express. I agree with @treefiddy on all comparisons.