# Is there something like tomcat for node.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, tomcat, npm, deployment

Some application server with an administration interface where I can deploy node.js application, view log files, start/stop/restart/monitor running applications?

Answer (score 0):

Tomcat and Node are completely different beasts, although you can get Node to serve the same purpose as Tomcat if you're agnostic to the programming language you're going to use and you add the right stuff on top of it.

- Tomcat is a web server for web applications written in java.
- Node is a runtime environment for applications in javascript.

But for monitoring you can you PM2 (https://www.npmjs.com/package/pm2)

PM2 is a production process manager for Node.js applications with a built-in load balancer. It allows you to keep applications alive forever, to reload them without downtime and to facilitate common system admin tasks.

Starting an application in production mode is as easy as:

```
$ pm2 start app.js
```

Credits and Read More: [How Node.js is different from Tomcat](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36636790/how-node-js-is-different-from-tomcat)